# Carry another person's Green Card to Mexico. Is this OK or legal?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, paperwork, legal, us-residents

friend A and B travel to mexico.  friend A accidentally brings expired green card instead of current/valid green card.  airline rejects friend A from returning to USA and recommends they go to embassy or consulate.  friend B returns to USA and will be returning to mexico with friend A’s current green card the following day.  plan is to return to USA together the next day.  is there anything to worry about?  they are worried most about friend B being asked why they returned to mexico after one day and are returning once again to the usa.  should they just tell the truth or is transporting someone else’s green card not ok?  thanks SB

Comment: What are A and B's nationality / residency status ?

Comment: @AakashM A is obviously a US LPR.  I don't suppose A's citizenship matters; am I overlooking something?  B's citizenship and residence status may matter in terms of ease of crossing the border, but that's really ancillary to the central question, which seems to be whether one may be open with border officers (in either country) about the reason for the trip and the quick return.

Comment: While this seems perfectly valid, why not use the mail system it's literally designed to ship items. With a tracked package, the likelihood of being lost in negligible. Friend A could also cross the border by road with the expired green card, avoiding the need for Friend B to make the second trip.

Comment: Did friend A point out to the airline that the US government allows airlines to board people with expired 10-year green cards for travel to the US?

Comment: @phoog If B is a US citizen, or Mexican citizen, or both, or neither, the treatment by border control might well differ. If there's one thing we know about border control, it's that status matters...

Comment: @AakashM a US LPR who has been absent from the US for 180 days or less is generally not considered an applicant for admission for the purpose of US immigration law, so has nearly as strong a right to enter the US as a US citizen, needing only to prove that the length of the absence was indeed 180 days or shorter.

Comment: @phoog I know nothing about the specifics of this question, but I do know that questions on this site about border crossings often benefit from the inclusion of nationality and residence information. If I *had* the relevant domain knowledge, I'd probably consider putting it in an answer (hint hint)

Comment: @AakashM I'm not adding an answer because there's a perfectly good answer already as far as US law is concerned, and I don't know about Mexican law.  Nationality and residence information is typically required to answer questions about visa requirements.  This question is not about visa requirements.  While B's nationality and residence do indeed have a bearing on the probability of being questioned, this question isn't about the probability of being questioned but rather about how to handle being questioned if it does happen.

Comment: update: A and B made it back to the USA. thanks for your comments and input.

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Instead, **[accept the answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer)** that you found most helpful. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/140506)

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing inherently wrong with this plan. However US Customs and Border Protection has a fair bit of leeway and discretion (to put it politely) and it's entirely possible that Friend B will be subjected to a substantial questioning or no questioning at all.

If questioned its typically best to be open and stick with the actual facts plus any documentation that can help supporting them.

The alternative would be to have friend B return to the US as planned and then simply overnight ship the Green Card to friend A in Mexico with a suitable courier. That's safer and probably cheaper too.

Comment: The shipping may be cheaper but there is always the chance that the package will get lost or delayed or delivered to the wrong location.  That will be minimized with a human courier.

Comment: If B is a US citizen or LPR, and if carrying the green card is permitted, US CBP officers have very little leeway or discretion.  But what about Mexican border officers?

Comment: @phoog What GC?  I just have a wallet full of credit cards, one of which may look like a GC

Comment: @PeterM that approach certainly won't help.

Comment: @phoog If the authorities are searching my wallet then I already have a lot of explaining to do

Comment: A signed statement from the Green Card holder explaining the situation and authorising Friend B to retrieve and bring the GC to him may simplify the whole affair.

Comment: @PeterM all the more reason to avoid antagonizing them with frivolous arguments such as that one.

Comment: @MarkJohnson indeed.  Even if it's legal to bring someone else's green card to them, carrying someone else's green card without their permission surely is.  But anyone can sign a letter saying "I, A, authorize B to bring me my green card."  A notarized letter would be more credible.  But frankly I don't think that "being asked why they returned to mexico after one day and are returning once again to the usa" is all that likely.  There is a lot of frequent travel back and forth.

Comment: @phoog One good get it witnesed by the Mexicam police, togeather with a copy of the passport page. If the signatures are all the same, that should even statisfy a curious Mexican official on the way back.

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of people that cross the border every day, so it should not be anything suspicious if you do it too. It is perfectly legal to go or fly to Mexico to eat dinner and them come back two hours later.
Also, as others mentioned, mailing is perfectly fine. Replacement Green Cards come in the normal mail, as do passports, drivers licenses, etc. Of course there is the small risk of loss (with ugly consequences), but if you insure the mail the chance is negligible.

Comment: JonathanReez and Aganju, the OP specified airline, so not land border crossing.

Comment: Insured mail can be lost or stolen as easily as uninsured mail.  And the insurance payment may make you feel better, but it will be money, not a replacement green card!